# Set value of all fields with a partial name in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of fields in a form, all with a prefix in the name. How can I use jquery to set them all to a certain value?

Comment: if you face problem, why you are not using custom attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute contains selector `[att*=val]`, or attribute is equal to or begins with followed by `-` selector

[6.3.1. Attribute presence and value selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-representation#attribute-representation)

> `[att|=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute, its value
>   either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately
>   followed by "-" (U+002D)

```js
$("form [name|=prefix]").attr("value", function(i, el) {
  return "123"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="prefix-a" />
  <input name="prefix-b" />
  <input name="prefix-c" />
</form>
```